# Turning my Euler function in to a higher order Runge–Kutta (RK4) that runs with an O(h^4) algorithm?

Tags: python, higher-order-functions, runge-kutta

I currently have the below as my Euler function but i would like to try this same function using the Runge-Kutta method as i believe it is more accurate

```
def Euler(U,V,n,dt):
    images = []

    for i in range(n):

        Uc = U[1:-1, 1:-1]
        Vc = V[1:-1, 1:-1]

        U[1:-1, 1:-1]=Uc + dt * (Du * laplace(U,hx,ht) + F(Uc,Vc))
        V[1:-1, 1:-1]=Vc + dt * (Dv * laplace(V,hx,ht) + G(Uc,Vc))

        U=periodic(U)
        V=periodic(V)

        if i % 500 == 0:
            images.append(V)

    return images
```

I have tried to do this below however i can't get this to run at all

```
def RK4_2_d(U,V,t,c):

    for k in range(len(t)-1):
        uu=np.zeros((U.shape[0],V.shape[0]))
        K1=ht*c*laplace(U[k,:,:],hx,hy);uu[1:-1,1:-1]=K1
        K2=ht*c*laplace(U[k,:,:]+uu/2,hx,hy);uu[1:-1,1:-1]=K2
        K3=ht*c*laplace([U[k,:,:]+uu/2,hx,hy);uu[1:-1,1:-1]=K3
        K4=ht*c*laplace(U[k,:,:]+uu,hx,hy)   

        K1=ht*c*laplace(V[k,:,:],hx,hy);uu[1:-1,1:-1]=K1
        K2=ht*c*laplace(V[k,:,:]+uu/2,hx,hy);uu[1:-1,1:-1]=K2
        K3=ht*c*laplace(V[k,:,:]+uu/2,hx,hy);uu[1:-1,1:-1]=K3
        K4=ht*c*laplace(V[k,:,:]+uu,hx,hy) 

        U[1:-1, 1:-1]=Uc + dt * (Du * laplace(U,hx,ht) + F(Uc,Vc))
        V[1:-1, 1:-1]=Vc + dt * (Dv * laplace(V,hx,ht) + G(Uc,Vc))

        U=periodic(U)
        V=periodic(V)

        if i % 500 == 0:
            images.append(V)
    return images
```

Am i going the right way about this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
"I can't get it to run" is not a problem specification: give us the problem data and output per the above coding standards.  If the problem is internal, show us your attempt to trace the mechanics therein.

Comment: It would be easiest if you could extract the ODE functions, intermediate would be `dU/dt =FU(t,U,V), dV/dt = FV(t,U,V)`, for a more general implementation `dY/dt = F(t,Y)`, where `Y=np.concatenate([U,V])` etc.

Comment: "Kutter" is a fishing boat, "Kutta" is the name of Martin _Wilhelm_ K., probably with some slavic origin.

Comment: At the very least you need to re-establish the periodicity in the stage evaluation points `U[k,:,:]+uu/2` etc.